# Updating widget after radio button has been selected

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

```
l1=Label(frame_two, text="Critique Status:", fg ='white', font=('Comic Sans',45, 'bold'))
l1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='NW',padx = 0, pady = 0)
l2=Label(frame_two, text="Please select from the following options below", fg='white', font=('Comic Sans',27,))
l2.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='E',padx =50, pady=20)

Frame for displaying 3 Media (entertainment) options
frame_three=tk.Frame(entertainment_critique_window, width=642, height=200,
highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=6)
frame_three.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NE', padx=5,pady=175)
frame_three.grid_propagate(False)

radiobutton_variable = IntVar()
Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Cinema - Hoyts",variable = radiobutton_variable, value = 1).grid(row = 4, column = 0,pady=15)
Radiobutton(frame_three, text="TV  - Channel 7",variable = radiobutton_variable, value = 2).grid(row = 5, column = 0,pady=15)
Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Radio - Nova 100",variable = radiobutton_variable, value =    3).grid(row = 6, column = 0,pady=15)

def update_status():
    radiobutton_variable = radiobutton_variable.get()
    if radiobutton_variable == 1:`
        print ('You have selected Cinema - Hoyts') 
    elif radiobutton_variable == 2:
        print ('You have selected TV  - Channel 7')
    elif radiobutton_variable == 3:
        print ('You have selected Radio - Nova 100')
```

I'd like to know how to update the "Please select from the following options below" text, when any of the 3 radio buttons are selected.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `command` option for the radio buttons?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  Re-wrote script.

The correct way to write  one line in `update_status()` function.

Also in `Radiobutton`  add keyword `value=`.

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

entertainment_critique_window = Tk()

frame_two= Frame(entertainment_critique_window, width=642, height=200,
highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=6)
frame_two.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='NE', padx=5,pady=175)

radiobutton_variable = StringVar(entertainment_critique_window, 1)

def update_status():
    l2.config(text='you have selected ' + str(radiobutton_variable.get()))

l1=Label(frame_two, text="Critique Status:", fg ='Blue', font=('Comic Sans',45, 'bold'))
l1.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='NW',padx = 0, pady = 0)
l2=Label(frame_two, text="Please select from the following options below", fg='red', font=('Comic Sans',27,))
l2.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='E',padx =50, pady=20)

#Frame for displaying 3 Media (entertainment) options
frame_three=Frame(entertainment_critique_window, width=642, height=200,
highlightbackground='black', highlightthickness=6)
frame_three.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky='NE', padx=5,pady=175)
frame_three.grid_propagate(False)

 r1 = Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Cinema - Hoyts",variable = radiobutton_variable,  value='Cinema - Hoyts', command=update_status)
r1.grid(row = 4, column = 0,pady=15)

r2 = Radiobutton(frame_three, text="TV  - Channel 7",variable = radiobutton_variable, value='TV  - Channel 7', command=update_status)
r2.grid(row = 5, column = 0,pady=15)

r3 = Radiobutton(frame_three, text="Radio - Nova 100",variable = radiobutton_variable, value='Radio - Nova 100', command=update_status)
r3.grid(row = 6, column = 0,pady=15)

entertainment_critique_window.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the help, however it still doesn't update. Any thoughts?

Comment: @TP JJB. Is this OK?. You can sue your layout.